# How to rewrite htaccess rules in windows plesk server

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess

I have a website which i made in php and i host it in a linux shared hosting . Now for some purpose i uploaded this site to windows dedicated server.Everything works fine except the htaccess rules which i wrote not working and i am getting 404 error(The requested path not found in server). I found some articles get to know i have to convert htaccess to web.config file. The htaccess i am using inside a folder and i have no idea where should i put the web.config file

```
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?$       index.php?PG=$1
```

This rule is inside a folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
<rewrite>
    <rule name="rule 1A">
        <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?PG={R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rewrite>
```

And save in web.config

Comment: If i have two parameters then how i do it .